# Rails ActiveRecord condition (date range between) not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do a simple query of all `Events` that have the `scheduled_date_start` between a specific date range. I have the following ActiveRecord expression:

```
now = Date.today - 1        # start date
sixWeeks = (now - 42)       # exactly 6 weeks ago
start = (sixWeeks - 6)      # start of valid date 6 weeks ago

@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {:scheduled_date_start => start.to_date..sixWeeks.to_date})
```

This seems to work but I am noticing that it does not work on the very last date. eg: If the date range is between 2014-01-28 - 2014-02-03, the result does not contain events that have a `scheduled_date_start` of `2014-02-03`.

Anyone know why that is?

Here is the SQL query that runs:

```
SELECT * FROM `events` WHERE (`events`.`scheduled_date_start` BETWEEN '2014-01-28' AND '2014-02-03') AND (events.deleted_at IS NULL OR events.deleted_at > '2014-03-18 09:08:41')
```

Comment: If scheduled_date_start is of type date_time then it would contain the time and in such a case for example '2014-02-03 11:01AM' would be later than the 'pure date' '2014-02-03' which would evaluate to '2014-02-03 00:00AM'.

Comment: Hmmm that looks like it might be the issue. Events that should be showing up have a `scheduled_date_start` of `2014-02-03 19:00:00`. Any way I can force it to compare my date only (no time)?

Comment: I'm not really sure about how BETWEEN behaves in such a case, but you could simply add another day. There are some ways to use SQL to convert between datetime and date, though those may not be compatible between databases and you would have to write rather ugly SQL queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you need

```
@events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => {:scheduled_date_start => start.beginning_of_day..sixWeeks.end_of_day})
```

Comment: Nce one, I always forget this end_of_day thing exists, leaving me with the ugly possibility of the edge case of a record created at 0:00AM.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Chears :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that it will help you :

```
@events = Event.where("scheduled_date_start between ? and ? ", start.to_date, sixWeeks.to_date)
```